# Get ID using join based on most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables:

Orders

```
order_id   total
1          5
```

Invoices

```
order_id  invoice_id  ship_date
1         a           1/1/2020
1         b           2/2/2020
```

I need to get the earliest ship date and the invoice_id of the latest date.  So the query should return the following:

```
order_id   total    latest_invoice_id  earliest_ship_date
1          5        b                  1/1/2020
```

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    order_id, 
    total,
    earliest_ship_date,
    latest_invoice_id
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                order_id, 
                min(ship_date) as earliest_ship_date, 
                max(invoice_id) as latest_invoice_id
            FROM Invoices
            GROUP BY order_id) i ON o.order_id = i.order_id
```

Of course this doesn't work because all I do is get the highest invoice_id using alphabetical order.  How can I get the invoice ID of the latest ship date in this case?

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?  SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and conditional aggregation. I find that a lateral join is handy here:

```
select o.*, i.*
from orders o
cross apply (
    select 
        max(case when rn = 1 then invoice_id end) latest_invoice_id,
        min(ship_date) earliest_ship_date
    from (
        select i.*,
            row_number() over(partition by order_id order by ship_date desc) rn
        from invoices i
        where i.order_id = o.order_id
    ) i
) i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for ranking and then arrive at the result

```sql
;WITH CTE_Invoices AS
(SELECT o.Order_Id,O.total, i.invoice_id,i.ship_date
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Order_Id ORDER BY ship_date DESC) as rnk_latestInvoice,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Order_Id ORDER BY ship_date) AS rnk_shipdate
FROM Orders as o
INNER JOIN Invoices as i
ON i.Order_Id = o.Order_ID)
select Order_Id, total , MAX(CASE WHEN rnk_latestInvoice = 1 THEN invoice_id END) as Latest_Invoice_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN rnk_shipdate = 1 THEN ship_date END) as earliest_shipdate
FROM CTE_Invoices
GROUP BY  Order_Id, total
```